# texcl, escapeinside, and single character comments, with listings package

Tags: listings, comments

I'm using the excellent listings package to typeset some code in a language very similar to Scheme.  The language has one type of comment:  when an (un-escaped) semicolon is encountered, the rest of the line (including the semicolon) is ignored (as a comment).  While only the single semicolon is necessary to introduce a comment, coding convention uses `;;;`, `;;`, and `;` to designate different levels of comments, as in

```
;;; Top level comment
(define (foo x)
  ;; within body comment
  (list x x)) ; after line comment
```

I'd like to use listings `texcl` option to typeset all comments using LaTeX, and have been able to do that so far.  I'd also like to use `\label{...}` to support later references to particular lines of code.  I can do this with the regular comments when `texcl` is turned on, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lstset{%
  comment=[l]{;},
  texcl=true,
}
\begin{lstlisting}
  ;;; top level
  (defun foo (x) 
    ;; in body
    (let ((y (+ x 1))) ; on line
      y)) ; \label{code:y}
\end{lstlisting}
Cross-reference to line \ref{code:y}.
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: sample of listings]

The problem is that the comment with the label, `; \label{code:y}` still displays the leading semicolon.  `listings` has an `escapeinside` option that can be used to escape to LaTeX, as in the sample from the documentation:

```
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
    { comment }(*@\label{comment}@*)
end;
\end{lstlisting}
Line \ref{comment} shows a comment.
```

The documentation also points out that the closing escape delimiter can be `\^^M`, to support escapes that are terminated by newlines, as in `escapeinside={//*}{\^^M}`.

What I'd like to do is use something like `escapeinside={;@}{\^^M}` to provide LaTeX escapes that are still within a comment in the programming language, e.g., (modified from above):

```
\lstset{%
  comment=[l]{;},
  texcl=true,
  escapeinside={;@}{\^^M}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
  ;;; top level
  (defun foo (x) 
    ;; in body
    (let ((y (+ x 1))) ; on line
      y)) ;@ \label{code:y}
\end{lstlisting}
```

but this produces an error (which only occurs while using the `texcl` option):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lst@next ->\lst@c;1 ;

l.14   ;;
         ; top level
```

Is there a way to fix this, or another way to get the desired behavior (i.e., comment lines generally set with LaTeX with semicolons displayed, but supporting some escape-to-LaTeX beginning with `;` in which the semicolon will not be displayed)?

As a temporary workaround, I can define the standard comment sequence to be `;;`, and the escaping-comment sequence to be `;@`; this works without a problem, except that I no longer have support for comments beginning with a single semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `morecomment` to add the sequences `;;` and `;;;`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{%
  comment=[l];,morecomment=[l];;,morecomment=[l];;;,
  texcl=true,
  escapeinside={;@}{\^^M},
  numbers=left
}
\begin{lstlisting}
  ;;; top level \LaTeX
  (defun foo (x) 
    ;; in body
    (let ((y (+ x 1))) ; on line $y=x+1$
      y)) ;@ \label{code:y}
\end{lstlisting}
A reference to line~\ref{code:y}
\end{document}
```