# texcl and range prefixes in listings with shorter comments

Tags: listings, comments

I'm trying to use the line range markers from the `listings` package to include sections of code.  I'd previously been using actual line numbers, but based on the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113080/29288), I've been able to gradually transition to using markers.  It seems that if multiple line comment sequences have been defined (e.g., with `comment=[l]{;},morecomment=[l]{;;}`) as is sometimes necessary (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118780/29288)), and the `texcl` option is used, then line range prefixes that are comments must include the longest such comment form.

For instance, the following MWE defines `;` and `;;` as introducing comments, and uses the `texcl` option, but does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{%
  texcl=true,%
  comment=[l]{;},%
  morecomment=[l]{;;},%
  rangeprefix=;MARK\ ,%
  includerangemarker=false,%
}

\begin{lstlisting}[linerange=lineTwo-lineFour]
lineOnee
;MARK lineTwo
lineThree
;MARK lineFour
lineFive
;MARK lineSix
lineSeven
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[linerange=5-7]
lineOne
;MARK lineTwo
lineThree
;MARK lineFour
lineFive
;MARK lineSix
lineSeven
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The error is

ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

```
--- TeX said ---
\lst@next ->\lst@c;1 M

l.26 ;M
       ARK lineFour
--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

Commenting out the `texcl=true` option will make this example compile, but I need the `texcl` option.  Alternatively, changing the rangeprefix to `;;MARK\` (and updating the listed code appropriately) also works, and is the workaround I'm using.  I am fine with this workaround, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to use `texcl`, `;` and `;;` as comments, and have a range prefix begin with a single `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to be partially related to the lack of space between your `;` and `MARK`.  One work around is to make sure you mark lines are formatted in the same way as the simple comments, i.e., as `; MARK`.  Note that these range markers are an experimental feature of `listings`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{%
  texcl=true,%
  comment=[l];,%
  morecomment=[l];;,%
  rangeprefix=;\ MARK\ ,%
  includerangemarker=false}

\begin{lstlisting}[linerange=lineTwo-lineFour]
lineOnee
; MARK lineTwo
lineThree
; MARK lineFour
lineFive
; MARK lineSix
lineSeven
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[linerange=5-7]
lineOne
; simple comment on line two
; MARK lineThree
lineFour
lineFive
; MARK lineSix
lineSeven
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{rangeprefix=;;MARK\ ,}
\begin{lstlisting}[linerange=5-7]
lineOne
; simple comment on line two
;;MARK lineThree
lineFour
lineFive
;;MARK lineSix
lineSeven
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good catch on the spaces, I hadn't thought to try modifying the spacing.  Any idea why issue this didn't seem to come up in the earlier questions, i.e., why using `;;MARK ...` didn't cause a problem?

Comment: It is only an issue when (a) you have a range markers set that do fit partially but not exactly with the comment style and (b) try to use a numerical range of lines that includes a line with such a marker.

Comment: By the way, this was the reason that I had such an hard time applying the previous solution to my document.  I had a number of `\lstlisting`s to convert from line numbers to range markers.  I added the range markers and updated the first `\lstlisting`, but that pushed up the line numbers, so the code in the second `\lstlisting` that still used line numbers then contained a range marker.